# Implement AsyncSocket callbacks in a swift class

Tags: ios, swift

I have a custom ViewController delegate class, which handles ui actions such as button clicked and display text in a text view.

Now I want to use AsyncSocket in the class. I have been able to create a socket object

```
var tcpSocket = GCDAsyncSocket(delegate: self, delegateQueue: dispatch_get_main_queue())
```

Now I want to implement those callback functions, such as didConnectToHosts(...) whose declaration is provided in GCDAsyncSocket.h:

```
- (void)socket:(GCDAsyncSocket *)sock didConnectToHost:(NSString *)host port:(uint16_t)port;
```

How do I implement this function in my swift class?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
// - (void)socket:(GCDAsyncSocket *)sock didConnectToHost:(NSString *)host port:(uint16_t)port;
func socket(socket : GCDAsyncSocket, didConnectToHost host:String, port p:UInt16) 

// - (void)socket:(GCDAsyncSocket *)sock didReadData:(NSData *)data withTag:(long)tag;      
func socket(socket : GCDAsyncSocket, didReadData data:NSData, withTag tag:Int32)
```

Don't forget to make your swift class inherit from NSObject, otherwise the GCDAsyncSocket will fail to assign it as a delegate.

Also, do not mark any parameters as `var` as in `var didReadData data:NSData`

Comment: One newbie question. Why my class doesn't have to inherit GCDAsyncSocketDelegate defined in GCDAsyncSocket.h to receive callbacks?

Comment: Probably because the GCDAsyncSocket class specifies `delegate` as plain `id` without the protocol. For example, look at the `setDelegate:(id)value` Swift translates `id` into `AnyObject?` and the call into `setDelegate(value:AnyObject?)`. If the GCDAsyncSocket developer had specified the protocol: `setDelegate:(id<GCDAsyncSocketDelegate>)value`, the Swift would be `setDelegate(value:GCDAsyncSocketDelegate?)` and you'd have to subclass GCDAsyncSocketDelegate in your class.

Comment: Is there possibly an issue with this in Swift 3? I am running into the issue where didConnectToHost doesn't get called. I looked at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35805299/gcdasyncsocket-in-swift) thread as well and while no error is getting thrown, the callback is not getting called.

Comment: @Anton Could you please give a complete minimal example?