# GCDAsyncSocket in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, sockets, tcp, gcdasyncsocket

I want to open a TCP connection with an OBD dongle based on ELM327 chip. So I have decided to use GCDAsyncSocket library. I wrote this code,

```
import UIKit
import CocoaAsyncSocket

class ViewController: UIViewController, GCDAsyncSocketDelegate {

    let addr = "192.168.0.10"
    let port:UInt16 = 35000
    var socket:GCDAsyncSocket!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        socket = GCDAsyncSocket(delegate: self, delegateQueue: dispatch_get_main_queue())
        do {
           try socket.connectToHost(addr, onPort: port)
        } catch let e {
           print(e)
        }

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
       // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func connect(sender: AnyObject) {
      print("Clicked")
    }

   func socket(socket : GCDAsyncSocket, didConnectToHost host:String, port p:UInt16)
   {
       print("Connected to \(addr) on port \(port).")
   }
}
```

but when I run the code , the function:

```
func socket(socket : GCDAsyncSocket, didConnectToHost host:String, port p:UInt16)
```

never gets run.

Where is the problem?

Can anybody advice me  about how to transmit  and recive literal  byte string.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I also had a problem, and I solve it like below.

You have to make class inherit from NSObject.

```
import Foundation
import CocoaAsyncSocket

public class MySocket: NSObject, AsyncSocketDelegate {

    var mSocket: AsyncSocket!

    override init() {
        super.init()

        let mSocket = AsyncSocket.init(delegate: self)
        do {
            print("Connecing to socket server...")
            try mSocket.connectToHost("google.com", onPort: 80)
        } catch let error {
            print(error)
        }
    }

    @objc public func onSocket(sock: AsyncSocket!, didConnectToHost host: String!, port: UInt16) {
        print("success")
    }

}
```

Below link can help you.

[Implement AsyncSocket callbacks in a swift class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24217106/implement-asyncsocket-callbacks-in-a-swift-class)

Answer (score -1):

FYI, if anyone else is running into the problem where didConnectToHost is not being called and seem to have tried everything else: I realized I was initializing my socket service class in my AppDelegate. When I moved the code elsewhere it worked and the callback was called.